# Data Matching with SQL and assigning Identity ID's

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity, matching

How to write a query that will match data and produce and identity for it.

For Example:

```
RecordID | Name
1        | John
2        | John
3        | Smith
4        | Smith
5        | Smith
6        | Carl
```

I want a query which will assign an identity after matching exactly on Name.

Expected Output:

```
RecordID | Name  | ID
1        | John  | 1X
2        | John  | 1X
3        | Smith | 1Y
4        | Smith | 1Y
5        | Smith | 1Y
6        | Carl  | 1Z
```

Note: The ID should be unique for every match. Also, it can be numbers or varchar.

Can somebody help me with this? The main thing is to assign the ID's.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. welcome to SO. We'd prefer not to write the code for you, but instead help you debug after you've tried it out yourself. Could you give it a shot and show us what you've tried?

Comment: How are you coming up with the values in your ID field?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Wax. Sure. Let me share what I did

Comment: @AbeMiessler Those are dummy values.

Comment: @bluefeet SQL server.

Comment: So you don't care what format the id column is in as long as it is a unique value for that particular group of names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
with temp as
(
select 1 as id,'John' as name
union
select 2,'John'
union
select 3,'Smith'
union
select 4,'Smith'
union
select 5,'Smith'
union
select 6,'Carl'
)

SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER
(ORDER BY Name) as NewId
FROM TEMP
Order by id
```

The first part is for testing purposes only.

Comment: Perfect. It works wonderfully. Thank you very much. Hey! Can you please suggest me some book to learn this type of querying?

Comment: I'm not much of a book reader.  Just keep at it and come here when you get stuck is my advice.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
SELECT *,
Rank() over (order by Name ASC) 
FROM table
```

Comment: The values are not unique for each partition. What I mean is For John twp values are being assigned 1 and 2, Similarly for Smith 1, 2 and 3.  I would like John as just 1 and smith as just 2.

Comment: Corrected. Please try now.

Comment: Rank() function isn't working for some reason. Dense_Rank is working though.

Comment: @John: I thought that is available in every SQL Server, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102(v=sql.110).aspx . Which one SQL Server you are using?

Comment: @Wawrzyneic Rank() is working but not according to our needs. Also, I am using SQL server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

This structure seems to work:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table 
    (
    Department VARCHAR(100),
    Name     VARCHAR(100)
    );

INSERT INTO #Table VALUES
('Sales','michaeljackson'),
('Sales','michaeljackson'),
('Sales','jim'),
('Sales','jim'),
('Sales','jill'),
('Sales','jill'),
('Sales','jill'),
('Sales','j');


WITH Cte_Rank AS
(
SELECT [Name],
       rw = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Name])
FROM   #Table 
GROUP BY [Name]
)
SELECT  a.Department,
        a.Name,
        b.rw
FROM    #Table a
        INNER JOIN Cte_Rank b 
        ON a.Name = b.Name;
```